# how to plot a linear regression in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a linear regression of length weight relationship
using this data set in R.

```
Species            length   weight

 1 YFT                   48   2.17
 2 YFT                   49   2.31
 3 YFT                   50   2.45
 4 YFT                   51   2.6 
 5 YFT                   52   2.75
 6 YFT                   53   2.91
 7 YFT                   55   3.25
 8 YFT                   57   3.62
```

I have tried this:

```
yft_tuna$logL <- log(yft_tuna$length)
yft_tuna$logW <- log(yft_tuna$weight)

lm1 <- lm(logW~logL,data=yft_tuna)

yft_tuna <- plot(yft_tuna,xlab ="lenght",ylab="weight",main="YFT")
```

I received this error message instead of getting the plot

```
Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: Your current example has you plotting your data set and not your lm...so it should be `plot(lm1,..)`.  Also, why are you overwriting your data frame with the plot?

Comment: `plot(yft_tuna$logL, yft_tuna$logW,  etc)` Also, there is an argument `log`, like this: `plot(yft_tuna$length, yft_tuna$weight, log = "xy", etc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you do not apply the `plot` function correctly. The function plots `y` against `x` by `plot(x,y)`. The arguments "xlab" and "ylab" merely name the axes of the plot.
I think what you want to do is:

```
plot(yft_tuna$length, yft_tuna$weight)
```

This however does not plot the results of your linear regression but just the data.

EDIT:
What I guess you want to do is to plot the data and then add a regression line. This you can do by:

```
plot(yft_tuna$length, yft_tuna$weight)
abline(a=lm1$coefficients[1], b=lm1$coefficients[2])
```

Comment: thanks. changed it.